# How to fix error wrong result in calculator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, calculator

I tried to code calculator program by react native.
I got one problem when I was using it.
When I click number and operator and number, it update slow. And the result in program,it is not correct.
I don't understand, it return result wrong
This is my file App.js

**File App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  const [listnumber, setlistnumber] = useState([]);
  const [newarrleft, setnewarrleft] = useState([]);
  const [newarrright, setnewarrright] = useState([]);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(0);

  const InputNumber = useCallback(
    (number) => {
      setlistnumber([...listnumber, number]);
    },
    [listnumber]
  );
  const DisplayResult = useCallback(() => {
    let vt = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < listnumber.length; i++) {
      const element = listnumber[i];
      if (element !== "+") {
        setnewarrleft([...newarrleft, element]);
      } else {
        vt = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    for (let k = vt + 1; k < listnumber.length; k++) {
      const element = listnumber[k];
      setnewarrright([...newarrright, element]);
    }
    //đổi mảng thành chuỗi
    let strleft = newarrleft.join("");
    // console.log(strleft);
    let strright = newarrright.join("");
    // console.log(strright);
    //lấy ra operator
    let filtered_operator = listnumber.filter(function (item) {
      return isNaN(item);
    });
    let operator = filtered_operator.join("");
    // console.log(operator);
    let kq;
    if (operator === "+") {
      kq = Number(strleft) + Number(strright);
    } else if (operator === "-") {
      kq = Number(strleft) - Number(strright);
    } else if (operator === "x") {
      kq = Number(strleft) * Number(strright);
    } else if (operator === "/") {
      kq = Number(strleft) * Number(strright);
    }
    setResult(kq);
  }, [newarrleft, newarrright, result]);
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.screen}>
            <TextInput style={styles.input} />
            <Text style={styles.screenresult}>{listnumber}</Text>
            <Text> = {Number(result)}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.gridlineone}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnac}>
              <Text style={styles.textac}>AC</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btndel}>
              <Text style={styles.textdel}>Del</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnpercent}>
              <Text style={styles.textpercent}>%</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btndivision}
              onPress={() => InputNumber("/")}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textdivision}>/</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.gridlinetwo}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btnnumberseven}
              onPress={() => InputNumber(7)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textnumberseven}>7</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btnnumbereight}
              onPress={() => InputNumber(8)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textnumbereight}>8</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btnnumbernine}
              onPress={() => InputNumber(9)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textnumbernine}>9</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btnmulti}
              onPress={() => InputNumber("x")}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textmulti}>X</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.gridlinethree}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btnnumberfour}
              onPress={() => InputNumber(4)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textnumberfour}>4</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btnnumberfive}
              onPress={() => InputNumber(5)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textnumberfive}>5</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btnnumbersix}
              onPress={() => InputNumber(6)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textnumbersix}>6</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btnsubtraction}
              onPress={() => InputNumber("-")}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textsubtraction}>-</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.gridlinefour}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btnnumberone}
              onPress={() => InputNumber(1)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textnumberone}>1</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btnnumbertwo}
              onPress={() => InputNumber(2)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textnumbertwo}>2</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btnnumberthree}
              onPress={() => InputNumber(3)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textnumberthree}>3</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btnaddition}
              onPress={() => InputNumber("+")}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textaddition}>+</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.gridlinefive}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btnnumberzero}
              onPress={() => InputNumber(0)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textnumberzero}>0</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btndecimal}>
              <Text style={styles.textdecimal}>.</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnresult} onPress={DisplayResult}>
              <Text style={styles.textresult}>=</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Please help me,thank you everyone.

Comment: There's a typo in your code: the division ("/") executes a multiplication ("*"). That might be the reason for the inaccurate results.

Comment: I don't understand. In code i have write Number(strleft) * Number(strright); and Number(strleft) * Number(strright);

Comment: So, if the user types in "/", you want "*" to execute? (So, if the sign for division is typed in, you want multiplication the execute?)

Comment: Thank you @muka.gergely, I realized I wrote the wrong code :)